# Using parallelism with linq

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a foreach loop with some results from a linq query.  I am trying to get it to run faster (it's taking about an hour to run) but when I convert to Parallel.foreach, the results I get are different that when I run with the standard foreach, even though it cuts the time in half.  Can those of you who are much better at linq and parallelism help me out some on this.

Really would like some way to speed it up.  I'm a bit confused though why the parallel.foreach is not giving me the same results.  Maybe someone smarter than I can fill me in.

The standard foreach:

```
var studentTestGroup = from st in this
                                   group st by new { st.TestName, st.STI }
                                       into studentGroups
                                       select new { TestName = studentGroups.Key.TestName, STI = studentGroups.Key.STI, students = studentGroups };
            //Loop through each group that has more than one test, or where there exists any retests at all.
            foreach (var studentGroup in studentTestGroup.Where(t => t.students.Count() > 1 || t.students.Any(x => x.Retest == "Y")))
            {
                if (studentGroup.students.Any(t => t.Retest == "Y") && studentGroup.students.Count(t => t.Retest == "N" || t.Retest == "") == 1)
                {
                    //For a test name and STI, if there exists a restest and only 1 non-retest, keep highest and disacrd the rest
                    var studentToKeep = studentGroup.students.OrderByDescending(t => t.TestScaledScore).First();

                        this.RemoveAll(t => t.STI == studentGroup.STI && t.TestName == studentGroup.TestName && t.PrimaryKey != studentToKeep.PrimaryKey);
                }
                else if (studentGroup.students.Any(t => t.Retest == "Y") && studentGroup.students.Count(t => t.Retest == "N" || t.Retest == "") > 1)
                {
                    //For a test anem and STI, if there exists a restest and more than 1 non-retest, 
                    //then keep the highest (number of non-retests) scores and discard the rest
                    int numRetests = studentGroup.students.Count(t => t.Retest == "N" || t.Retest == "");
                    var studentsToKeep = studentGroup.students.OrderByDescending(t => t.TestScaledScore).Take(numRetests);

                        this.RemoveAll(t => t.STI == studentGroup.STI && t.TestName == studentGroup.TestName && !studentsToKeep.Any(x => x.PrimaryKey == t.PrimaryKey));
                }
                else if (studentGroup.students.Any(t => t.Retest == "Y") && !studentGroup.students.Any(t => t.Retest == "N" || t.Retest == ""))
                {
                        this.RemoveAll(t => t.STI == studentGroup.STI && t.TestName == studentGroup.TestName && Convert.ToInt32(t.TestScaledScore) < 400);
                }
            }
```

The part where I converted to a parallel foreach:

```
Parallel.ForEach (studentTestGroup.AsParallel().Where(t => t.students.Count() > 1 || t.students.Any(x => x.Retest == "Y")).AsParallel(), studentGroup =>
            {
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not combine PLinq(AsParallel) and TPL(Parallel.ForEach). That will even decrease speed because you overload thread pool. Use one of technics. All you can get from parallelism is speed up in your CPU cores count. After that you can use some profilers. Or heuristics about collections that only you know. 
For the code you provided - do not duplicate instructions! For example:

```
studentGroup.students.Count(t => t.Retest == "N" || t.Retest == "")
```

you can calculate it only once instead of every-time in all different conditions.
Same goes to:

```
studentGroup.students.Any(t => t.Retest == "Y")
```

"Any" will iterate your entire collection till predicate match, so just not iterate large collections multiple times for all if-statements with the same condition!
Question yourself about collections, maybe you could use dictionaries for search items or some other structures, but as I said that would be more like heuristics for your collections that maybe provide some speed up.
Hope this helps. 
If you want more then you need profilers.

Answer (score 1):

What is type is `this`?

I think there is a race condition on `this.RemoveAll()`. If you modify a list/collection in multiple threads at the same time the result of the operation on the collection isn't clear.
In this case you could use a lock statement around your `RemoveAll()`-calls, but then the benefit of your parallel foreach would be gone.

Another possibility could be to remember all items which should be removed and remove them after the foreach. I think an add-operation on a collection should be possible on multiple threads.

Edit:
This may could be a faster implementation to remove the specified items:

```
List itemsToRemove = new List();
foreach (var studentGroup in studentTestGroup.Where(t => t.students.Count() > 1 || t.students.Any(x => x.Retest == "Y")))
{
    int countNo = studentGroup.students.Count(t => t.Retest == "N" || t.Retest == "");
    bool anyYes = studentGroup.students.Any(t => t.Retest == "Y");
    if (anyYes && countNo == 1)
    {
        var studentToKeep = studentGroup.students.Single(t => t.Retest == "N" || t.Retest == "");

        itemsToRemove.AddRange(t => t.STI == studentGroup.STI && t.TestName == studentGroup.TestName && t.PrimaryKey != studentToKeep.PrimaryKey);
    }
    else if (anyYes && countNo > 1)
    {
        var studentsToKeep = studentGroup.students.Where(t => t.Retest == "N" || t.Retest == "");

        itemsToRemove.AddRange(t => t.STI == studentGroup.STI && t.TestName == studentGroup.TestName && !studentsToKeep.Any(x => x.PrimaryKey == t.PrimaryKey));
    }
    else if (anyYes && countNo == 0)
    {
        itemsToRemove.AddRange(t => t.STI == studentGroup.STI && t.TestName == studentGroup.TestName && Convert.ToInt32(t.TestScaledScore) < 400);
    }
}
foreach (var itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
{
    this.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
```

Comment: "this" is inherited from a list.  Sorry I didn't specify.

Comment: I added a sample code to my post. May this could help you.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions and see what kind of speed improvements I get.

Comment: That dropped it from an hour to about 40 minutes.  Pretty good speed-up

Comment: I have just seen that you can remove `anyYes` from the foreach body and from all if/else if conditions. This check is done in the foreach head. You also should try the parallel foreach for the first loop. I think this could work now.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I really didn't even know about the profiler.  I've got it down from an hour to about 2 minutes now.